# Graph API for monitoring storage capacity of Power platform environments from a third party monitoring tool

Tags: power-platform

Is there any API to retrieve the storage capacity usage of different environments in Tenant so that we could alert to users if storage capacity exceeds certain threshold.
We are using a third party monitoring tool and would like to send alerts for the same.

I could not find any API details to get the storage capacity information from Power Platform?

Can someone please help on this?

[Storage has exceeded 80% of capacity and would like to retrieve the capacity usage information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUGYw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this article that describes how to build a "Daily Capacity Report" with PowerShell or Power Automate:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/programmability-tutorial-create-daily-capacity-report?tabs=PowerShell

Hope it helps